# Notation question A $\subset \subset B$

Tags: functional-analysis, notation

I am a bit confused about the notation A $\subset \subset B$ used in functional analysis. The definition I have says: $A \subset \subset B$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $\bar{A}$ compact in $B$.
Wikipedia on the other hand says that in addition to that $\bar{A}$ may not touch $\partial B$.

My question is now which definition is the correct one? And is the open unit ball $B_1(0)$ relative compact in the closed unit ball: $B_1(0) \subset \subset \bar{B}_1(0)$?

Comment: I'd say it means that the closure of $A$ is contained in the interior of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $A \subset \subset B$ implicitly presupposes that $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of some Hausdorff space $X$, for example $X=\mathbb C^n$.
In that case it means that the closure $\overline A$ of $A$ **in $X$** is a compact subset of $B$.
This is the usual  interpretation, for example  the one adopted by Hörmander's classic  [An introduction to complex analysis in several variables](http://books.google.fr/books/about/An_introduction_to_complex_analysis_in_s.html?id=rWIPAQAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)  (cf. page xi).

So indeed you may write $B_1(0) \subset \subset \bar{B}_1(0)$ .
Note, however, that  the notation  $A \subset \subset B$ is usually used only when $A$ and $B$ are *open* subsets of $X$.  In that case $\overline A$ is automatically disjoint from  $\partial B$, just as Wikipedia claims.

Comment: Hörmander uses it (like it's usually used) to denote that $A$ is relatively compact in $B$. In a Hausdorff universe that implies that the closure of $A$ is contained in $B$, but it says more.

Comment: @Daniel: oops, you are right: I misstated what I meant. Now corrected. Also,  I assume that the ambient space $X$ is indeed Hausdorff. As an algebraic geometer I work with non Hausdorff spaces all the time,  but then I call *quasi-compact* a space having  finite subcoverings for open coverings. A compact space is then a Hausdorff quasi-compact space. But since in real or complex finite-dimensional analysis (in particular in Hörmander's book) spaces *are* Hausdorff, I didn't want to go into this distinction between compact and quasi-compact. Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: In some contexts (non-linear functional analysis), $A\subset\subset B$ does not presuppose that the two have the same topology. For example, see [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem).

Comment: Yes, compact = quasicompact + Hausdorff, that's uncontroversial (well, it _should_ be, but like $0\in\mathbb{N}$, it isn't, unfortunately). Assuming that the ambient space is Hausdorff is reasonable, since the notion of relative compactness in non-Hausdorff spaces is a little messy.